# Execute saved query

Tags: ms-access

My query is below to update SQL server data which is saved on pass through query - "qryPassThroughUpdate".

```
UPDATE Invoice SET PaidAmount=0, Unpaid=9954.88, Instance = Instance + 1, UpdateByID=10, 
UpdateTime='9/24/2020 2:31:10 PM', [_FID_PaymentStatus]=50 WHERE [_ID] = 24123
```

I got warning message, if I double click query directly and it does update on SQL server.

[image]

I want to use VBA code to run query and update SQL server.  My code is below.

```
CurrentDb.Execute "qryPassThroughUpdate"
```

[image]

On the query SQL, it is not SELECT query.  Not sure how to run saved query through VBA code.

Comment: Use DoCmd.OpenQuery "qryPassThroughUpdate" and it works now.  OpenQuery will have warning message and need to disable it.

Comment: The first error message says (in other words): "Open the query in design view and show the query properties window. Then, set the ReturnsRecords property to false".